# python open the latest excel file

Tags: vba, python-3.x

I recently started using python 3.6 (trough Anaconda) so I am sorry if the below will result not that clear. The situation is the following:

I have an excel file, which I use to run a macro in order to obtain results from Prophet. My macro works good but, unfortunately, after several times it has been used excel reaches the limit of memory and I cannot extract the results anymore. The way to solve the problem would be to close excel and then open it again.

To do so, in the same vba macro, I open a python script that allows me to run the macro, save the excel file, close it and open it again. The macro is the below:

```
import win32com.client 
object = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
object.visible=1
object.Run("Central_Run")
print("Macro ran successfully!")
print("Active WB:", object.ActiveWorkbook.Name)
for wb in object.Workbooks:
print("WB:",wb.Name)
wb.Save()
#The loop above saves all the workbooks that are open
object.quit()
#Open the Excel file again
object=win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb=object.Workbooks.open(‘myfile.xlsm')
```

The script works, however, I would like to open the excel file, in the second part of the script, without specifying its name (wb=object.Workbooks.open(‘myfile.xlsm')), so that I can use the code for other similar excel files with different name. Ideas that I had were either to open the latest used excel file or to link the script to a specific cell in my excel file so that I need just to modify that cell instead of the script, but, unfortunately, I am not able to do it. 
Thanks in advance for the help! :)

Comment: Not sure what you'd like to do.  Do you want to open a 'blank' spreadsheet and then copy a macro from a different spreadsheet in it?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for not being clear with the above. The steps should be the following:
1) Open excel worksheet which contains 2 macro; the first to open python and the second to extract results from Prophet (the name of the file is "myfile.xlsm")
2) Run the macro to open the Python script (script is in the above question);
3) With the Python script I run the macro in the excel of point No.1. In the same script I save and close every excel worksheet I have open.
4) In the Last part of the macro I would like to open again the excel file of point No.1 without using its name ("myfile.xlsm").

Comment: The main aim is to use the python script for different excel file without being obliged to change the code (in the part where I defines the name of the excel file) every time I adapt it to the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your second print statement with this:

```
wbName=object.ActiveWorkbook.Name
print("Active WB:", wbName)
```

and then replace the last line with:

```
wb=object.Workbooks.open(wbName)
```

Comment: Hi. Many thanks for your response! it works for the original file! However, I wanted to apply the script to a new excel file (just a copy of the original excel) named: "myfile - Copy.xlsm". Doing so, I receive the following error:
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'myfile - Copy.xlsm' could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct.\n\nIf you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently used files, make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or deleted.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Comment: Might this be due to the fact that, after defining wbName, I have a line which quits the object (object.quit)?